Does wrapping entire app in a client side component makes the app a client side rendered application in NextJS?

In NextJS doesn't wrapping layout.js content with SessionWrapper
which is a client side component makes the entire app client side
rendered?

Someone please explain in detail, Why layout.js content is still rendered on server side?


layout.js file :
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import SessionWrapper from "@/components/SessionWrapper";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <SessionWrapper>
                    <Navbar />
                    <div className="text-white min-h-screen relative">
                        {children}
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                </SessionWrapper>
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}

SessionWrapper component :
"use client"
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react"

export default function SessionWrapper({children}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      {children}
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

its written clearly that  my app should become client side rendered when wrapped in a client side component (session wrapper). but it doesnt not. can anyone tell me why?

if you are rendering with ssr or ssg, the component in _app.js would be server component .when we pass server component to client component the server component renders on server and along with placeholder in client component is sent to client where further rendering takes place.
if you are rendering with csr entire render process takes place on client

Questions :

In next.js doesn't wrapping layout.js content with SessionWrapper which is a client side component makes the entire app client side rendered?


No, it won't make whole app  client side rendered.
NextJS allows passing as props (Server & Client Components) in client components, but doesn't allows importing a Server Component into a Client Component.[1]
This is because props can change, but when you import a component it gets added in the file permanently.
Server Components are added by ReactJS as childrens after processing
RSC Payload [2].

How a page gets generated which contains both Server & Client Components :

When a request is made to the server, all Server Components are rendered first, including those nested inside Client Components (as props). [2]

Client Component doesn't know that children (props) will eventually be filled in by the result of a Server Component. The only responsibility Client Component has is to decide where children will eventually be placed.[2]

React renders Server Components into a special data format called the React Server Component Payload (RSC Payload).[2]

RSC Payload contains[3]:

result of Server Components,

Placeholders for where Client Components should be rendered and references to their JavaScript files,

Any props passed from a Server Component to a Client Component



Next.js uses the RSC Payload and Client Component JavaScript instructions to render HTML on the server.

On the client this HTML is used to immediately show a fast non-interactive preview of the route - this is for the initial page load only. [2]

The RSC Payload[3] is used to reconcile the Client and Server Component trees, and update the DOM.[2]




Why layout.js content is still rendered on server side?

By default, Next.js uses Server Components[4]. layout.js is Server Component by default[5].

Further :
If you want to see RSC recieved on frontend
You can see RSC in Network tab,
For ex. I created a folder in app directory as about with page.js in it just containing a div
<div>Dummy Content</div>

Then in browser, navigate to http://localhost:3000/about
Open Network tab you will see Name about, click on it then see
Headers > Response Headers > Vary : RSC...

Also now click on Preview, it will show you Server rendered HTML.
If you also add a Client component in it about page.js, it will just show basic HTML.

Read More:

Supported Pattern: Passing Server Components to Client Components as Props : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#supported-pattern-passing-server-components-to-client-components-as-props

Interleaving Server and Client Components : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#interleaving-server-and-client-components

React Server Component Payload (RSC) : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#what-is-the-react-server-component-payload-rsc

Nesting Layouts (Good to know Section) : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/layouts-and-templates#nesting-layouts

Using Server Components in Next.js : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#using-server-components-in-nextjs

How are Server Components rendered? : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components#how-are-server-components-rendered

How are Client Components Rendered? : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components#how-are-client-components-rendered

Moving Client Components Down the Tree : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#moving-client-components-down-the-tree


